# SSMS Permission Denied, Login with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio) version 16.4, Windows 7. First install is normal use, sometimes i reinstalling my Windows and just now i install SSMS again, and got this problem.
I cannot do anything except view.

Object Explorer & Registered Servers Display

[image: Object Explorer & Registered Servers Display]

- BUILTIN\Users (ServerRole: Public) > using windows authentication
- sa (ServerRole: Public, Sysadmin) > SQL Server Authentication (with default password)

I cannot create any database, restore or anything that change the content of my server. Also i have try to Add new login, and i don't have permission to create new login. I run the SSMS as Administrator, but i still cannot do anything.

Anyone know how to add new logins from out of application. Maybe i can connect to Server with SQL Server Authentication that have all permission that required. Or any way to solve this permission problem.

Thanks

Attach Database -> Add

[image: Attach Database]

Restore Database

[image: Restore Database]

Try something to do
[image: Try something to do]

Error when add ServerRole to my `BUILTIN\Users`
[image: Error when add ServerRole to my <code>BUILTIN\Users</code>]

Connection Properties if needed.
[image: Connection Properties if needed.]

Answer (score 3):

You are just a member of `BUILTIN/Users` when connecting to SQL Server, your `USER\Administrator` is not a member of `sysadmin` role, so you have no server permissions. Try to execute

```
select * 
from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'server');
```

and all you see will be `CONNECT SQL` + `VIEW ANY DATABASE`.
Of course you cannot use `DAC`, you are NOT `sysadmin` to be able to do it.

What you should do instead is launch your server in `single user mode`, and as you are local admin, you'll be able to log in as `sysadmin`.
After that you should add yourself to `sysadmin` role.

Here are the steps to perform: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

@Muhamad Sofyan, I have gone through your error log as it's showing the `Microsoft SQL server , Error : 916`.

**Reasons for SQL Server Error 916**

Here are some possible reasons for SQL Server Error 916:

```
 1. A login does not have permission to view data of a column selected
    in the header 

 2. A database is offline and/or its collation is NULL

 3. Multiple databases with different collations are on the instance and
    SSMS is unable to retrieve the collation because a database is
    configured to auto-close
```

For Correct `SQL Server Error 916` follow the steps [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2761/sql-server-management-studio-error-916/)

**Note:** In your case the error comes from the database is in `model` database

Comment: Like you said, login does not have permission, the problem my `BUILTIN/Users` just have `public` permission. I follow the steps, and stuck when login with `sa` account. I browsing for a while to get the default password of `sa` account, and i don't get the right password to use.

Comment: @Muhamad Sofyan, Did you try through DAC login.

Comment: I am sorry, what is DAC? If windows account, I set only administration account on my windows.

Comment: @MuhamadSofyan https://www.brentozar.com/go/dac

Comment: >>>Did you try through DAC login<<< To be able to login using DAC, one should be **sysadmin**, and he is NOT

Comment: >>>In your case the error comes from the database is in model database<<< In his case the error is the lack of permissions. And the only mode to get the permissions is to grant them to him by sysadmin.

Answer (score -4):

query keyin

```
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'Domain\User' 'sysadmin';
```

It works for me.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you explained how it addressed the problem, and how the OP can execute the query without a functioning SSMS.